# "getDate().toJSON()" loses a day

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs, pikaday

I'm using the [pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) date picker plugin (through an [angular directive](https://github.com/nverba/pikaday-angular) and with [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)) and sending the value to the server. Converting to json seems to lose a day though:

```
var d = myPikaObject.getDate();
console.log(d);              // Thu Apr 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (SAST)
console.log(d.toJSON());     // 2015-04-29T22:00:00.000Z
```

I think this is a momentjs problem but I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: It isn't losing a day at all. see that GMT+0200? what would the date be if you took away 2 hours?

Comment: I think you may be confusing changing to use a different timezone from losing a day. I had this happen to me due to differences in browser and server timezones.

Comment: losing a day = hour difference due to timezones lol.

Comment: curses and all I need is the date - I thought T22 was a reference to the timezone lol. Thanks

Comment: `toJSON` outputs an ISO time string. `console.log` outputs a locale time string. That the difference. No time loss.

Comment: @jcuenod No, `T22:00:00.000` means 22 (hour) 00 (minute) 00 (second) 000 (millisecond). There's no **timezone** in an ISO time string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving you're already getting time with **momentjs**, you can try `moment.utc()` method. The docs say:

> As of version 2.0.0, a locale key can be passed as the third parameter
>   to moment() and moment.utc()

```
moment('2012 juillet', 'YYYY MMM', 'fr');
moment('2012 July',    'YYYY MMM', 'en');
```

You can do a lot more with the utc() method.

```
moment.utc();
moment.utc(Number);
moment.utc(Number[]);
moment.utc(String);
moment.utc(String, String);
moment.utc(String, String[]);
moment.utc(String, String, String);
moment.utc(Moment);
moment.utc(Date);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using `moment(d).format("YYYY-MM-DD")` (where d is the variable in the question above).

Comment: Happy to help! May be you'd also upvote, since this helped? :)

Answer (score 5):

It's all about the format of your date.

When you juste print d, you have this :

```
Thu Apr 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (SAST)
```

It's GMT +2, so when you print d.ToJson() you lost 2 hours. So you are the day before at 22pm

Comment: Okay, I get the problem. Thank you! How do I get the right date though?

Comment: Store the timezone as well, then when you parse it later, take the time zone into consideration. Or, don't use `.toJSON()`, use `.toString()` instead.

Comment: *"How do I get the right date though?"* Always store the date/time in UTC. Only convert to local time for display purposes.

Comment: @FelixKling I get the logic of what you're saying and under usual circumstances I would but to be honest it seems to me that there are types of dates that shouldn't be localised: a birthday, for example, is just connected to a date not a "localisable" date/time and if you move to New Zealand you just get to have your birthday sooner.